# Communicating with a TCP socket (server)

Tags: r, sockets

I am trying to send text to a server listening on a TCP port with R, and then read the response text from the server.
Quite trivial, i.e., on the BASH for a server listening to port 12345, that is:

```
 > echo "text" | nc localhost 12345
 response
```

The server keeps running and can be queried any time again after this.
But if I try the same thing from within R with socketConnection, I either never get a response, or it is printed and not captured.
I have tried the following:

```
  con <- socketConnection(port=12345)
  con <- socketConnection(port=12345, blocking=TRUE, timeout=2)
  writeLines("text", con) # server does not receive a thing
  flush(con) # has no effect
  readLines(con) # still, nothing happens and gets nothing back
  close(con) # server confirms receipt, but I no longer can get the result...
```

The server only receives the data after closing the connection, so nothing can be read

```
  con <- pipe("nc localhost 12345")
  writeLines("text", con)
```

Now, "result" is printed to STDOUT, so I cannot capture it...
If using a temporary file that contains "text":

```
  res <- readLines(pipe("nc localhost 12345 < tempfile"))
```

That works, but requires an intermediate, temporary file.
How do I get server communication to work in R so that I can write and then read from the same connection?

Comment: Does the example on ?socketConnection shed any light, e.g., R process 2 use of `isIncomplete()`, maybe preceding the readLines with `writeLines("text", con2)`

Comment: No, I'm not trying to communicate between two R processes; what they are doing there is waiting for incoming data on the "server". My problem is sending in the first place: R does somehow not seem to send my request until I manually close the connection to flush it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I compiled and ran this [simple server](http://www.binarytides.com/server-client-example-c-sockets-linux/), leading to

```
Socket created
bind done
Waiting for incoming connections...
```

Then in  R I created a connection

```
con <- socketConnection("127.0.0.1", port = 8888)
```

the server responded

```
Connection accepted
```

and back in R...

```
writeLines("all the world's a stage", con)
x = readLines(con)
x
## [1] "all the world's a stage"
close(con)
```

to which the server responded

```
Client disconnected
```

and then quit, as expected. Not sure how this differs from what you've tried.

Comment: Well, maybe then the server is the issue, somehow. I am using a Scala package called factorie [http://factorie.cs.umass.edu/usersguide/UsersGuide200QuickStart.html ] as sever ("fac nlp"). I assumed since this is a well established library, it could not be the issue!

Comment: Just for reference - there was indeed a problem with the Scala code of factorie. Hope they accept my fix...